# SuiteScript Cannot read property 'Dialog' of undefined

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have a few scripts that work for me and some of them have been working for days. Suddenly I have been receiving the error, "Cannot read property 'Dialog' of undefined" in two of my scripts.

Neither of the scripts have Dialog written in them. They do have dialog. This is one of the scripts.

```
define(['./pws_shared', 'N/ui/dialog'],
function(shared, dialog) {
    function saveRecord(scriptContext) {
        var rec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        var status = rec.getValue({fieldId: 'status'});
        if(status == shared.CONSTANT.CASE.STATUS.CLOSED.VALUE)
        {
            var resolution = rec.getValue({fieldId: 'custevent_leak_closefix'});
            if(!resolution)
            {
                dialog.create({
                    title: "Warning",
                    message: "Please select the resolution of the case."
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return {
        saveRecord: saveRecord
    };

});
```

As you see, no reference to Dialog at all, only dialog. And it works for me. Some employees are getting the error and I am getting emails with the error from NetSuite.

The shared script is only a list of constants.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ensure that u can get dialog box

Answer (score 0):

make sure the module definition for `'./pws_shared'` loaded correctly. If it didnt load, then you have a definition offset in which `shared` becomes `dialog` because pws_shared didnt load. Has happened to me

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would this still be the issue if it works for me ?

Comment: Also if shared didn't load, wouldn't the error be thrown on this line
if(status == shared.CONSTANT.CASE.STATUS.CLOSED.VALUE)
saying CONSTANT does not exist in shared?

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the SuiteAnswers article "**Working with Online Forms**", you are limited to make use of some API for online forms. I tested with the dialog module, and it didn't work even when I declared it in the script, and got "*Cannot read property 'Alert' of undefined*", cause it needed a module which wasn't loaded. Maybe this can help you next time.

Good luck